# fetch multiple value from same table using id value

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch value Rows from single table.I want to fetch sub_id for specific id.

I achieved my require ment in 2 query.I want to do it in single query.I want to display result as Event,order history,Eent Ticket,calander

[image: []

```
$sql="select * from table1 where roles like %admin% and sub_id='0'"
$sql1=mysql_query($sql);
while($fet=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1))
{
 $id=$fet['id'];
 $query="select page_name from table1 where sub_id= '$id'";
  .. ..
}
```

Comment: did you have problem with nested query?

Comment: `$sql="select * from table1 where roles like %admin% and sub_id='0'"` in this query you are actually getting `page_name` also . No need of second query in while loop

Comment: Why are you fetching `page_name` again as it is already retrieved in your first query?

Comment: if sub_id = 0 in ist than how can u get sub_id= '$id' ?? in second query?

Comment: @user3386779 why would you select the `page_name` again?You already have it in `$fet` variable.

Comment: did u try my solution ??

Answer (score 4):

Use a `JOIN`

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.sub_id, t1.page_name, t2.page_name AS parent_page
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table1 AS t2 ON t1.sub_id = t2.id
WHERE t2.roles like '%admin%' AND t2.sub_id = '0';
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cdc17e/3)

Comment: I want to display result as Event,order history,Eent Ticket,calander

Comment: That's what this does, see the demo I added.

Comment: I understand what you want. Please see my sqlfiddle demo, it returns the rows that you want.

Comment: If you want them all in a single row, with comma separators, use `GROUP_CONCAT` to combine them.

Comment: Now Its displays the rows where sub_id is != 0 now.

Comment: Do you want to display the parent pages AND the child pages? The question says you just want to display the child pages. I've updated the query so it also returns the parent name for each child.

Answer (score 3):

use this

```
  $sql="select sub_id from table1 where id='".$id."' ";
```

After this, use results of this as below

```
  $sql= "select * from table1 where roles like %admin% and sub_id in($ids)";
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need another query to get the value of `page_name` just use `$fet['page_name'];` you already get the data of `page_name` in your first query.

```
$sub_id = $fet['sub_id'];//
echo $sub_id;//
$page_name = $fet['page_name'];//You can get and use the value of page_name here
```

**UPDATED**

if you want **Event,Order History,Event Ticket and Calander**

then change your where to `sub_id = '2'` ordered by id ascending.

```
$sql="select * from table1 where roles like %admin% and sub_id='2' order by id asc"
$sql1=mysql_query($sql);
while($fet=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1))
{
  echo $fet['page_name'].'<br/>';//display the page_name
}
```

Comment: No, he wants a different row that's linked to the row he fetched in the first query, where `sub_id = id`.

Comment: @Barmar Why OP need to query again, when he only needs to get the value of page_name? he already have it in `$fet` variable.

Comment: `$fet` is the ID of the parent page in the hierarchy. He wants all the pages in the next level.

Comment: @Barmar no, `$fet` is an associative array with the index of id,sub_id,page_name and roles with its corresponding value base on OP's first query.. why use `$fet['id']` just to select or get  the value of `sub_id`?there is no need to get the value of something that you already have.Isn't it a redundancy?

Comment: `$fet['page_name']` is `comments` and `Event Management`. He wants the child elements `Events, Order History`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the single query for getting `page_name`:

```
SELECT page_name FROM table1 
WHERE roles LIKE %admin% 
AND sub_id = 2
```

---

you can get **Event,Order History,Event Ticket,Calendar as:**

```
$sql="SELECT page_name FROM table1 
WHERE roles LIKE %admin% 
AND sub_id = 2";
$sql1=mysql_query($sql);

$records = array();
while($fet=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1))
{
    $records[] = $fet['page_name'];
}

echo implode(",",$records); // Event,Order History,Event Ticket,Calendar
```

**UPDATE 1:**

use `sub_id = 2` for getting all page_name related to Event MAnagement

**Side note:**

I suggest you to use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`, instead of `mysql_*` because `mysql_*` is deprecated in not available in PHP 7.

Comment: I need it in single query.

Comment: its single query brother @user3386779: SELECT page_name FROM table1 
WHERE roles LIKE %admin% 
AND sub_id > 0

Comment: I need to start from 0. fetching subchild

Comment: than barmar query place in the same code. @user3386779

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102562/discussion-between-devpro-and-user3386779).

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="select sub_id from table1 where id='".$id."' ";
```

if thats what you want.